# Google Analytics - grant "server app" permissions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using Google Analytics API - via. "server app" to fetch "WEB" data.
But can't get the "APP" data out of the API, so I can see the mobile data too.

When I'm using the console it works fine, but with my own account, and not that account the "server app" created.
Got 2 profiles, "WEB" & "APP" and using "~all" to fetch all profiles.
But can only see "WEB".

How do I grant permissions for server account?
Can I somehow test with that in the console, so I can see what data it should have got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log into the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and get the Service account Email address

```
<yourprojectid>-<longstring>@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

and then grant permissions to that service account email address through the web interface or through the API using the [following sample](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webpropertyUserLinks/insert).

```
# This request creates a new Property User Link.

analytics.management().webpropertyUserLinks().insert(
    accountId='123456',
    webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
    body={
        'permissions': {
            'local': [
                'READ_AND_ANALYZE'
            ]
        },
        'userRef': {
            'email': '<yourprojectid>-<longstring>@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
        }
    }
).execute()
```